# How can I list and block programs from ever running in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, resource-monitor

Whenever I start a gaming session, at some point I start getting major lagging from applications running in the background.

I always immediately tab over to my resource monitor and find that things like `lenovoUpdate` or `winch123fs1` or `setup.exe` running.  This is a brand new computer, so I'm pretty certain these are all "automatic update" items.

I'd like to block these items, and pretty much anything that I don't know what it is.  I know this is a bad idea, but I'll figure it out, and in the end I'll at least have some idea of what all this background stuff is.

**How can I get a list of all the programs that have ran (and perhaps when/ how much cpu theyused).  And from there, how can I start black-listing things I don't want running?**

In short, how can I have some amount of control over what's sucking up my CPU?

Comment: Open task manager and go to the startup tab, highlight and hit disable any items you don't want to start when windows loads, then restart your PC. See if that helps.

Comment: I would simply uninstall the application.  Of course a setup.exe wouldn’t be automatically started.